# Listitems not rendering after POST Request ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I have comment section in my app and I'm trying to add new comment with axios.post request.

Here it is (Sequelize,nodeJS) :
`let commentArrayNew=[]`

```
 app.post('/addComment/:id', (req, res) => {
    commentArrayNew.push(req.body.comment)
    Posts.update({
            comment: commentArrayNew
        },
        {
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        }).then((post) => {
        res.send(post)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
    });
    })
```

On my front-end side whenever I'm sending request it is giving me status 200 but it is not rendering new item on the page .

Here is my FE Request

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/addComment/${id}`, {
                comment: commentValue.value
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    window.location.reload();
                    const {comment} : any = res.data
                    if(commentValue) {
                        dispatch(actions.addComment({comment}))
                    }
                    console.log('--------location', location.state);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    toast.info("Server error")
                    console.log('--------err', err);
                })
```

I'm using useLocation to send state from another component:

```
 const grabCommentsFromLocation = () => {
    if (location.state) {
        let commentArray = location.state.post.items.comment
        let listItems = commentArray.map((item: Object[]) => {return <p key={uuidv4()}>{item}</p>})
        return listItems
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm rendering my items:

```
<div>
                    <p>Comment : </p>
                    {grabCommentsFromLocation()}
                </div>
```

And here is my dispatch function from redux:

```
export const addComment = (payload : any) => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload
}
}

 case actionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            posts : [
                ...posts,
                {
                    comment : action.payload.comment,
                }
            ]

        }
```

Even tho comment is saving into DB Items are still not displaying,Any suggestions why?

Comment: you are doing `window.location.reload` just after the API call, won't the data be lost?

Comment: Even if I remove that line I get the same result

Comment: Did you trying logging `action.payload.comment` inside your `ADD_COMMENT` action? Are the updated values available?

Comment: yes they are available

Answer (score 1):

you have to use res.status(200).json(post); instead res.send(post)

Comment: res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
try this bro

Comment: no errors just same result,it is not displaying on FE side

Comment: res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); add this before res.send

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217369/discussion-between-dharani-shankar-and-nika-roffy).